# What is a good C# compiler-compiler/parser generator?

Tags: c#, parser-generator

I'm looking for a parser generator that given an EBNF for a LL(k) language will give me a C# parser and generate classes the types defined in the EBNF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gold](http://goldparser.org/) is OK as far a parser generators go.

Comment: OP asked for LL(k).  Gold is LALR.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong: Are no LL grammars subset of LALR grammars?

Comment: @Saysmaster: No. Wikipedia says: "The LALR(k) parsers are incomparable with LL(k) parsers – for any j and k both greater than 0, there are LALR(j) grammars that are not LL(k) grammars and conversely. In fact, it is undecidable whether a given LL(1) grammar is LALR(k) for any k >= 0."

Comment: Would be nice, though to have a gold engine which generates the full parser code into 1 file and spares us to have dependencies. (e.g. for c#)

Answer (score 25):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (nothing else to say)

Comment: well you need to say something to get to 15 chars. ;) +1

Comment: I think ANTLR has real problems giving proper error messages. Good luck figuring out eg. where to put the @inlude specification!  Documentation is bewildering and never shows the preferred way to do stuff. Tree gramars are a waste of time.. the ANTLR site even has a huge blog entry on this.

Comment: Hmm, looks like http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target was last updated 3 years ago and all the code blocks are missing -- wait, no, that's just what happens when JavaScript is disabled. Anyway, C# has always been a second-class ANTLR target. When I first used it, the C# Runtime source code wasn't available: the author (not the same as the author of ANTLR) released the binary with no specified license IIRC, and dropped off the face of the earth. I used Reflector to reconstruct the source code.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new parser generator on the block called [LLLPG](http://ecsharp.net/lllpg/), that supports LL(k) grammars and zero-width assertions. The runtime library is optional (a base class suffices). The documentation is fairly detailed now, and I have used LLLPG to parse most of a dialect of C# called Enhanced C# (which, in fact, is the main input language of LLLPG). The input syntax is not EBNF, though (it's sort of a mashup of C# + ANTLR-style code).

Full disclosure: I wrote it. Questions welcome.

**Edit:** the top Google result for "C# parser generator" is written by a guy named "Tomassetti" who claims my parser generator "is not really usable standalone" - that's like saying a PC is "not really usable as a standalone gaming rig" because it can *also* do web browsing and spreadsheets. True, after installing the Visual Studio extension you must separately go to NuGet and get the runtime library (Loyc.Syntax), but I don't think that's what he means and I don't think he ever actually tried to use it. LLLPG's design is a feature, not a bug. All I can say is, please give it a try and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [MinosseCC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/minossecc.aspx), a port of `JavaCC` to C#. Another possibility is [Spart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spart.aspx).

Comment: MinosseCC was renamed to CSharpCC. 
The current version is on Google Code space and it's the port of JavaCC 3.2, while a development version (port of JavaCC 5.0) is under development on GitHub (http://github.com/deveel/csharpcc)

Comment: Spart is terrible; you can't get the AST from an expression. Instead, you have to subscribe to the Act event, which only returns the text matched as a string. This makes it pretty much useless. It is supposed to be a port of Spirit (for C++), but in practice, since it doesn't support this feature from Spirit, it is useless. (also the documentation is incorrect for even the trivial examples)

Answer (score 4):

Find Irony in http://irony.codeplex.com/

PROS: It is simple
CONS: -Lack of document
      -Rather Slow

Answer (score 2):

Grammatica supports LL(k). http://grammatica.percederberg.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Coco/R](http://ssw.jku.at/Coco/) (from the SSW - "Johannes Kepler" University Linz)