# Regex for picking up method name then literal strings in those methods?

Tags: regex

Looking for a regEx expression that will return the method name then the strings inside the method body, for each method. method name will always be between void and (

```
void MyMethodName(....)
{

   code

   code

   code "string 1"

   code "string 2"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the method name use this expression:

```
void (\w+)\(
```

The name will then be in the first group of the match.

**But** parsing a real programming language with regular expressions will not work (consider code fragments in string literals for example). I suggest that you look into parser generators:

[What is a good C# compiler-compiler/parser generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194584/what-is-a-good-c-sharp-compiler-compiler-parser-generator)